# How to use Z3 Context in Python api?

Tags: python, c++, z3, z3py

In C++, `z3::context context` generate a new context.Through this Z3 expressions with new context can be created as `context.bv_const(variable_name, 16)`.

How can the same behaviour be done using z3 python api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In z3py, the general use model is via a `Solver` object, which is backed-up by one global context. This simplifies programming, as end users need not worry about the details of context creation. From the documents:

```
  Z3Py uses a default global context. For most applications this is sufficient.
    An application may use multiple Z3 contexts. Objects created in one context
    cannot be used in another one. However, several objects may be "translated" from
    one context to another. It is not safe to access Z3 objects from multiple threads.
    The only exception is the method `interrupt()` that can be used to interrupt() a long
    computation.
```

So, it is indeed possible to create a new `Context` as well in z3py, should you choose to do so; though this isn't the general use model.

The API is designed such that most (if not all) methods take an optional context argument as their last argument. Regarding `bv_const` that you referred to, z3py version is:

```
def z3py.BitVecSort(sz, ctx = None)
```

(See https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#afbff817f0f2dbfb6b9bebd9d50598683)

As you can see, the last argument is the optional `ctx` parameter. If you do not provide one (which is the general z3py programming model), a global one will be used. However, you can pass your own, so long as you heed to warnings I quoted above. (That is, keep objects from different contexts separated at all times.)

You can read the `Context` class details here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_context.html